# Time complexity of this algorithm? How to analysis？

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Time complexity of this algorithm? How to analysis？

```
int fun(int n)
{
          int i = 0, j = 0, m = 0;
          for (i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
          {
                   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                   {
                             m += 1;
                   }
          }
          return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your running time is *Sum_i* *(n/2^{i})*, for *i* in *{0* to *log(n)}*. *n* is the leading term, thus *O(n)*. The sum will not exceed *2n*.